# How do US states decide whether to join a federal lawsuit?

Tags: united-states, us-states

I read on https://www.cnbc.com/2023/01/24/doj-files-second-antitrust-lawsuit-against-google.html:

> The states of California, Colorado, Connecticut, New Jersey, New York, Rhode Island, Tennessee and Virginia joined the DOJ in the latest lawsuit [against Google].

How do US states decide whether to join a federal lawsuit? I don't know if the reason is political or legal. If legal, feel free to migrate this question to [Law SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3):

It's generally the Attorney General's decision, at least directly (depending on the state, other parts of the government such as the legislature or governor may be able to threaten to remove the AG if they don't like their decisions, and governors might be able to give orders). Note that Merrick Garland, the federal AG, announced the suit, not Biden. There certainly is a political component to the decision to file a lawsuit, but legally, in court, a state is represented by the AG, and the power to act on the state's behalf lies in their hands.

> While varying from one jurisdiction to the next due to statutory and constitutional mandates, the role of attorney general typically includes: 
> Issuing formal opinions to state agencies 
> Acting as public advocates in areas such as child support enforcement, consumer protections, antitrust and utility regulation
>  Proposing legislation 
> Enforcing federal and state environmental laws 
>  Representing the state and state agencies before the state and federal courts 
> Handling criminal appeals and serious statewide criminal prosecutions 
> **Instituting civil suits on behalf of the state** 
> Representing the public’s interests in charitable trust and solicitations 
> Operating victim compensation programs

https://www.naag.org/attorneys-general/what-attorneys-general-do/
(bolding added)

> This is the latest legal action taken against Google by either the Justice Department or local state governments. In October 2020, for instance, the Trump administration and 11 state attorneys general sued Google for violating antitrust laws, alleging anticompetitive practices in the search and search advertising markets.

https://www.denver7.com/news/local-news/colorado-joins-doj-lawsuit-against-googles-online-advertising

This is why Politico considered the California AG to be  relevant:

> California filed on Friday to join the Justice Department’s antitrust suit against Google, becoming the first state led by a Democratic attorney general to participate in the case.

https://www.politico.com/news/2020/12/11/google-california-antitrust-lawsuit-444623

Comment: Of course, states can also only join lawsuits in which their state or residents of their state have an interest. A lawsuit related to state jurisdiction over ocean coastal areas, for example, would not be one that Utah or Kansas or Wyoming or Iowa could join. Similarly an antitrust lawsuit concerning grocery store chains without any stores in a Hawaii could not be joined by Hawaii. A lawsuit related to Colorado River water rights couldn't be joined by Pennsylvania or Florida. SCOTUS has held in 2020 that a state can't join a lawsuit over election administration in another state.

Comment: @ohwilleke So, hypothetically speaking, if Texas doesn't like how Pennsylvania is running their elections, and decide to sue them, the federal courts wouldn't look kindly on that?

Comment: @Accumulation Not hypothetically, but yes.